# Choose an amount of certain item from the database to save into a variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm trying to make a way to take a certain quantity of a product from all displayed from the database, for example I want to take 3 out of 5 possible ones with me but I have no idea what I need to add to make it so, right now it displays the data like this:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item ){

  $unitprice = $item->get_total() / $item->get_quantity();
  echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" .$item->get_name() . "|" . $item->get_quantity() . "|" . $item->get_total() ."'>";
  echo '<p>';
  echo __('Product name: ' ) . $item->get_name() . '<br>';
  if($item->get_quantity() > 1) {
    echo "Amount: " . "<input type='number' name='numberqty' value='" . $item->get_quantity() . "'max='" .$item->get_quantity() . "' min='0' > " . "<br/>";
   }     
   else {
    echo __('Amount: ' ) . $item->get_quantity() . '<br>';
  }
    echo __('Product individual price: ') . $unitprice . '€' . '<br/>';
    echo __('Product total: ' )  . wc_price($item->get_total()) . '</p>' . '<br/>';

 }
   echo '<p>'. __('Order total: ') . $order->get_total() . '</p>';
```

I'm not very good at making questions so ask if something is unclear.

Comment: Please specify more clearly what you want to do - to have better PHP code on server side, better view on HTML page or more correct data retrieval from MySQL. Thx

Comment: Well, basically, What I want from this specific code to do, is to allow me to select a certain number between 0 and the number that is input inside the database, and take along "that amount" of them

Comment: Well, start from https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question - it still seems very unclear